# Recovery of corrupted JPEG file taken using Canon Eos Rebel

Tags: data-corruption

I have a photo that was taken using a Canon Eos Rebel.

I cannot get it to show, and the file appears to be corrupted.

I've tried many of the free apps (Stellar, Wondershare Recoverit, and one paid one (Tenorshare) and haven't been able to retrive anything.

Does this mean it's a total loss?

Here is a link to the photo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aczo1AFsgdxjPkCqPMJJiKA-d_U1uzmO/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The file is totally corrupt. In my binary file browser, it looks like this, full of zeroes:

[image]

Another symptom is that it is only 800K, when JPEGs from these cameras are normally in the 7-10MB range.

Another way to check is to ZIP it. A normal JPEG is already compressed and you gain very little by putting it in a ZIP (size gains are a couple of percent at best). Here you go from 800K to 1061 bytes, so there is very little data in it.

What this means is that the file you extracted is worthless, but maybe another extraction from the media(*) with another tool could yield better results (though you tried a few already).

(*) SD card? I don't put too much trust in brand SD cards, and the no-name ones are handled with care, while I carry them to the nearest trash can.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at it for me.  I'm completely a newbie when it comes to anything like this, but your reply confirms what I already feared and had already found.  I had watched a lot of tutorials and done a lot of reading before posting here, and had read how the off brand SD cards are junk.  Do you have a recommendation of what media to save to?  Thanks again!

Comment: Currently AFAIK the best media for long-term storage is a hard disk (typically, portable USB hard disk). Even beats optical (DVD/CD). Tape is even better but  a lot more expensive at consumer level. SD cards are just a media to transfer you data between the camera and the PC. Have several, two 32GB ones are better than a single 64GB, and alternate their use.

Comment: Thanks so much for your expertise.  It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic types of file corruption.

A file is there, probably copied but tempered with. For example, at the beginning of a file, there is a description of what is inside the file. This data could have some scrambled digits. Sometimes this can be fixed or simply copy again the original data.

But the main type is that the physical device did not save all the data correctly.

A file recovery should be **on the original physical device**. There is no point in copying already corrupted data.

---

If the photo is really important, send both, the original camera with the original card to a specialized technician.